# rotation causes Svgs to be cut off

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, svg, transform

rotation of svgs, without it cutting off.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y2jLq8nh/)

```
    <div id='marker' style='display:none'>

     <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="450mm" height="450mm" id="svg111" version="1.1">
        <g id="trans" x='65' y='65' transform=' rotate(0)' >
           <path id="p1"fill="red"fill-opacity="1"d="M23.891,85.702c31.965-3.284,45.401-20.078,45.401-20.078l-0.017-0.015c0.01-0.01,16.158-14.203,17.963-46.274c-5.043-1.163-86.9-19.556-86.9-19.556l34.483,32.93L0.353-0.207C0.353-0.207,22.498,80.717,23.891,85.702z" />
        </g>

    </svg>
   </div>

    document.getElementById('svg111').setAttribute('transform', "rotate(" + Math.floor(Math.random() * 350) + 1 + ")");
```

im displaying svgs made in html and use that as markers for google maps, now the problem here is that `when i rotate these predefined svgs, they cut off, no matter what i do, they cut off.  now i understand this happens because it goes out of the view area, Iv been trying to make it display everything not matter what the degree of rotation, but it it seems it cuts off even if i triple the size of my svg.   also i need it to rotate on its tip, so putting the anchor for the rotation in the center is not a option sadly.   any nudge in the right direction would be appreciated

Comment: like it would be ideal if i could transform the svg as a whole on not just the insides with the path in